# What exactly does the FROM clause do in an UPDATE statement in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

To quote the PostgreSQL documentation on the update statement:

"When a FROM clause is present, what essentially happens is that the target table is joined to the tables mentioned in the from_list, and each output row of the join represents an update operation for the target table. When using FROM you should ensure that the join produces at most one output row for each row to be modified."

I have two questions:

1. What kind of join is performed between table and the tables mentioned in from_list? My intuition tells me it's a cross join. If not, is it an inner join? What condition does it join the tables on?
2. Can someone explain the second sentence quoted, and if possible, provide an example of where such precautions would need to be taken?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "join" is a `CROSS JOIN`, but this is usually mitigated by conditions in the `WHERE` clause:

```
update a
    . . .
    from b
    where a.x = b.y;  <-- turns this into an inner join
```

The second statement is simply that the conditions should result in only one row from `a`, so if there are duplicate matches in `b` (or any tables in the `FROM` clause), figure out how to reduce that to one reference per row in `a`.